# How to change value of child table after form submit?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm making a web app in Oracle Apex for a harbor (for my final project). I don't know how to handle a situation. So I made a calendar and I have 2 tables: 1) `VEZ` table that has `ID_VEZ`(number), `VEZ_NUMBER`(number), `VEZ_MAX_LENGTH`(float), `VEZ_STATUS`(varchar2, its a radio group with option 1) `'FREE'` and option 2) `'TAKEN'`. The other table is called `BROD` and it contains columns `ID_BROD`(number), `BROD_REGISTRATION`(varchar2), `DATE_OF_ARRIVAL` (date) , `DATE_OD_DEPARTURE`(date), `ID_VEZ_FK` (number, also in the form as a LOV that shows only `ID_VEZ` where `VEZ_STATUS = 'FREE'`.
Now my questions are:

1. How to make it so when the form for my table `BROD` is submitted and the data sent to the database that the `VEZ_SATUS` of the `ID_VEZ_FK` that was selected in the form is set to 'TAKEN' again so if I open another form for `BROD` i cant pick that `ID_VEZ_FK` again.
2. After that how do I change the `VEZ_STATUS` to 'FREE' once `DATE_OD_DEPARTURE` passed and/or the reservation is deleted.

TABLE VEZ describes a Harbor place and TABLE BROD describes a boat that arrived at that place.

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Do I need to do that in the SQL query or make a dynamic action or some third option?

I'm aware that my explanation is underwhelming but I will try to clear any misunderstanding in the comments so please comment away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of **1**: create a page process which updates vez status:

```
update vez v set
  v.vez_status = 'TAKEN'
  where v.id_vez = :P1_ID_VEZ_FK;
```

As of **2**: create list of values that displays only free vez numbers:

```
select v.vez_number as display_value,
       v.id_vez     as return_value
from vez v
where v.status = 'FREE'
order by v.vez_number;
```

---

I don't think that in reality you can rely on someone leaving on `DATE_OF_DEPARTURE`; what if someone dislikes that place and leaves earlier (so that vez is free several days earlier than it was planned) or later (so that vez isn't free on `DATE_OF_DEPARTURE`)? I think that you should create another form (or reuse existing one, if possible) so that you'd *manually* free that vez.

But, if you insist, then modify LoV `WHERE` clause to e.g.

```
where v.status = 'FREE' 
   or v.date_of_departure < sysdate
```

On the other hand, you should actually update vez status from "taken" to "free". If you do it manually, no problem. To automate it, create a stored procedure and **schedule** it using the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` built-in package.

Comment: I will try number one first thing after i come home.  About the 2nd one, how do i automaticaly set v.status back to 'FREE' once the DATE_OF_DEPSRTURE < CURRENT DATE ? also through a page process ?  Also thanks again for all the help you daved me !!!

Comment: Answer to that requires some more typing that doesn't fit the comment so I edited the answer. Have a look, please.

Comment: In case someone leaves early i have the the table VEZ as a interactive report so i can manualy change the Status to FREE. If someone stays longer i can always edit the calendar  entry and set a new DATE_OF_DEPARTURE. The problem is thaz DATE_OF_DEPARTURE is not in the table VEZ but in the table BRODICA. I have no idea what the DBMS_SCHEDULER is but i hope there are some Youtube videos about it !

Comment: Videos? No idea, but there certainly is **documentation** about it.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much once again !!!